# Unity 3D: How can I have directional light on for one camera and off for another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, game-engine

I need to show two camera display side by side. One will have the sun(directional light) on and one will have the sun off while rendering the same scene at the same time. I have tried to use sun.SetActive() inside of OnPreRender() method, for one Camera I set it sun.SetActive(false) and sun.SetActive(true) for another. It does not work, sun remains off for both camera. How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: Do both objects share the same script component? Curious if they are actually both being set to the same value. Or are you using tags to separate them?

Comment: No I am using separate script to control the sun(directional light) object. Two separate script for two camera. What I am trying to achieve is sunny display for one camera and sunless display for another camera. This two display will render side by side at the same time sothat we can see the effect of sun in one display and sunless effect in another display for comparison.

Comment: Hey I found the solution. It worked. The OnPreRender() has worked fine. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: well done! If you have a reproducible solution, post an answer to your own question so future readers can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add [OnPreCull](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreCull.html) too to your initial try for versions highers than Unity 4.6.

I preserve OnPrerender for older versions, you got an advice on your log but ignore it.

Add this script to your camera:

```
function OnPreCull () {
     if (sun != null)
         sun.enabled = false;
 }

 function OnPreRender() {
     if (sun != null)
         sun.enabled = false;
 }
 function OnPostRender() {
     if (sun != null)
         sun.enabled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this would be to have all gameobjects duplicated and set to different layers - e.g.: 'Sunlit' and 'Shadowed'. The duplicate object needs to be nested within the original object, which can be quite messy, you'd need a script to duplicate the scene's objects at runtime.

The hierarchy would look something like this:

[image]

Your directional light's culling mask (on the light's inspector) would be set to everything but to the objects on the 'Shadowed' layer.

Then 2 cameras, culling everything but one of the layers:
[image]

I'm unsure if this is better or worse than joreldraw's solution in terms of performance. But I would guess it would depend on the amount and complexity of the models. On joreldraw's solution we're enabling/disabling the lightsource several times per frame. With this solution we have twice the gameobjects. If you don't have a lot of objects on your scene, then perhaps this solution is better.